# How to start an application from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm getting started on the Ubuntu terminal.

How can I start an application (for example, `CompizConfig Settings Manager`) from the terminal?

Which command do I have to use?

Comment: You should ask this one at http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 14):

to run *Compiz Config Settings Manager* you have to type `ccsm`

full list of commands:

```
Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PLUGIN, --plugin=PLUGIN
                        Directly jump to the page of PLUGIN
  -c CATEGORY, --category=CATEGORY
                        Directly jump to CATEGORY
  -v, --version         Version
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe after you've installed compizconfig-settings-manager

You can then run

ccsm

This should bring it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and gradually you start remembering Therefore first you must understand the concept. Linux terminal is the way to interact with the overall Linux system that is underneath the Graphical environment.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what the command line name of an application is, you would need to check the files which get placed into the GUI menu. This is actually not very obvious any more and I can't point you to the answer directly...

If you open the `system-monitor` gui application, or run `top` in a shell, you will see the most active processes at any one time. Doing this whilst interacting with CCSM should help you to identify it's process name. On the command line, you can use tab completion (try typing `c-c-tab-tab` then `s-tab` and you'll see what I mean.

One small detail, if you run `ccsm` from the command line, the shell you are running will be suspended whilst that GUI program is running. You will see some output as it runs, then when you quit, the prompt will come back. An alternative it to type `ccsm &` which will allow the gui to run in the background in parallel with your shell.